# Computing a bound on the percentile of the normal distribution's CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ be a normal random variable and $\alpha>1/2$.

The $\alpha$ percentile of $X$ is usually denoted as $Z_\alpha$ and satisfies $\alpha = \int_{-\infty}^{Z_\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$.

I need to bound $Z_\alpha$ (as a function of $\alpha$) for analysis of an algorithm.

> **What would be a good function $f:[0.5,1)\to\mathbb R$ that that $\forall \alpha\in[0.5,1):f(\alpha)\ge Z_\alpha$ ?**

By good I mean a function that is of explicit form (no integrals and such) and satisfies $f(\alpha)\approx Z_\alpha$  (e.g., is there such function $f$ such that $f(\alpha)$ is always at most twice than $Z_\alpha$?).

Comment: $$\alpha = \Phi(Z_{\alpha}) \implies Z_{\alpha} = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$$

and the inverse CDF of the standard normal is implemented even in spreadsheet programs, so why not use it? It is not "closed form" in the pre-computers era sense of the word, but it is there for the using.

Comment: "No integrals and such" presumably would exclude power series, infinite continued fractions, and all other transcendental operations.  (If not, then @Alecos has already given the best possible answer.)  That leaves you only with rational functions (and possibly the greatest integer function), excluding all exponentials and logarithms even.  I believe there is no solution subject to such severe restrictions.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you are taking alpha>1//2.  Alecos Papadopoulos suggestion is fine.  I don't understand the need to produce a function with the restrictions you make.  Bill Huber is suggesting that your conditions may be too stringent.

Comment: Why do you say that you need to bound these percentiles?  Are your bounds two-sided?

Answer (score 2):

The following explicit bound should work:
\begin{align*}
\bar Z (\alpha) &= \sqrt{2\log\left(\frac{1}{2(1-\alpha)}\right)}
\end{align*}
The bound follows from the fact that $1-\Phi(z) \le \exp(-z^2/2)/2$ and that $\Phi(\cdot)$ is increasing in its argument.

Lower bounds on $1 - \Phi(z)$ (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.2063v3.pdf)) imply that $\bar Z (\alpha)$ is also accurate, up to a logarithmic correction. To see this, note that we get the following bound from the paper:
\begin{align}
1 - \Phi(z) &\ge \frac{z\, \varphi(z)}{1+z^2} \nonumber \\
&\ge \frac{\varphi(z)}{3z}, \text{ when } z \ge 1. \label{eq:lbnd}
\end{align}
Solving for $1 - \alpha = \varphi(\underline{Z}_\alpha)/3\underline{Z}_\alpha$ approximately gives the form:
\begin{align}
\underline{Z}_\alpha &= \sqrt{2\log\left(\frac{1}{C(1-\alpha)}\right) - \log \log \left(\frac{1}{C(1-\alpha)}\right)} \,\,.
\end{align}
Here $C$ is an explicit constant (say 10) and depends on the fact that we used 3 in the lower bound for $1-\Phi(z)$. Typical regimes of interest are when $\alpha$ is close to 1, where the choice of $C$ would not matter a great deal. In particular $\bar{Z}_\alpha/\underline{Z}_\alpha \to 1$ as $\alpha \to 1$. A very small correction to $\underline{Z}_\alpha$ shows that it gives an explicit lower bound to $Z_\alpha$.

Comment: This solution involves logarithms @whuber.  Where did the OP exclude logarithms. Looking at the paper it seemed that the proof involves continued fractions and Mills Ratio.  I may have missed it but I didn't see how the lower bound on 1-F(z) where F is the cumulative normal distribution shows that this approximation is accurate enough.

Comment: @Michael If you have the wherewithal to compute a log, you can compute an error function (with about the same computational effort).  However, this answer does provide an approximation that might be simpler to analyze mathematically, so I think it could have substantial value. (+1)